# Logging specific requests in a separate file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to log requests coming for a particular file, say collect.gif into a separate log file using .htaccess, it this is achievable ?

E.g 
http://www.domain.com/collect.gif?user=1&page=sample must alone get logged into a file collect.log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered almost exactly in the [`CustomLog` section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) of the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/).  Reproducing the relevant section here:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI \.gif$ gif-image
CustomLog gif-requests.log common env=gif-image
CustomLog nongif-requests.log common env=!gif-image
```

So for your situation, you would just change the `SetEnvIf` conditional to match the request you are after:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI collect\.gif$ gif-image
CustomLog gif-requests.log common env=gif-image
CustomLog nongif-requests.log common env=!gif-image
```